# What is the difference between maven surefire report plugin and maven surefire plugin

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

What is the difference between maven surefire report plugin and maven surefire plugin and when they will be used

Answer (score 3):

- **[maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/)** is designed for running unit tests and if any of the tests fail then it will fail the build immediately.
- **[maven-surefire-report-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/)** uses the generated *.xml files under /target/surefire-reports and creates web view of surefire test.

Answer (score 0):

The surefire plugin is used to run unit tests, while the surefire report plugin can be used to write a test report for the maven site.